# Is a proposition applying to all elements in a set the same as membership of the set implying the proposition holds for a given element?

Tags: logic

Let $A$ be a set and $P$ a proposition. I'm wondering whether the statement $$\forall x \in A, P(x)$$ is logically equivalent to the statement $$x \in A \implies P(x).$$ And if there is a difference, why?

Comment: In standard mathematical practice they mean the same thing, although the first has an assumed implication operation (and it is not clear whether the "for all $x$" extends only to "$x \in A$" or to all of "$x \in A \implies P(x)$", although to have the intended meaning it should extend to all of "$x \in A \implies P(x)$") and the second has an assumed universal quantifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they clearly are not the same thing.

- $\forall x\in A,P(x)$ is an alternative notation for $\forall x,(x\in A\to P(x))$. Both state that: "Every $x$ in $A$ satisfies $P(x)$".

  This is a universal quantified statement, where term $x$ is bound to the scope of the quantifier.
- $x\in A\implies P(x)$, says that: "Free term $x$ satisfies $P(x)$ is logically entailed by the claim that $x$ is in $A$."

  This is a logical implication between two sentences, were term $x$ occurs free in each.